# Packet Manager on Hue bridge

Tags: openwrt, u-boot, busybox, philips-hue, opkg

I have successfully jailbreaked my Hue Bridge 2.1 and now have Root Access over SSH to it.

But I don't know how I can Install a Packet Manager (like opkg) on it.
It looks like wget is installed, but nothing else really. Also SCP works.
I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work. (See console). (Full console dump [here](https://pastebin.com/nGLp9dUB))

```
login as: root
root@192.168.1.69's password:


BusyBox v1.23.2 (2018-10-25 16:12:28 UTC) built-in shell (ash)

  _    _ _    _ ______   ____       _     _              ___   __   __
 | |  | | |  | |  ____| |  _ \     (_)   | |            |__ \  \ \ / /
 | |__| | |  | | |__    | |_) |_ __ _  __| | __ _  ___     ) |  \ V /
 |  __  | |  | |  __|   |  _ <| '__| |/ _` |/ _` |/ _ \   / /    > <
 | |  | | |__| | |____  | |_) | |  | | (_| | (_| |  __/  / /_ _ / . \
 |_|  |_|\____/|______| |____/|_|  |_|\__,_|\__, |\___| |____(_)_/ \_\
                                             __/ |
                                            |___/
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Version: 1810251352
----------------------------------------------------------------------

root@Wohnzimmer:~# busybox --install opkg
--install: applet not found
root@Wohnzimmer:~# opkg
-ash: opkg: not found
root@Wohnzimmer:~# wget
BusyBox v1.23.2 (2018-10-25 16:12:28 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-U|--user-agent AGENT] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

        -s      Spider mode - only check file existence
        -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q      Quiet
        -P DIR  Save to DIR (default .)
        -O FILE Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
        -U STR  Use STR for User-Agent header
        -Y      Use proxy ('on' or 'off')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just install the packet manager using  `busybox --install opkg` or`sudo apt-get install <any-package>`.

This below error message clearly says the `opkg` packet is not found, you need to build the source, and add that in your target.

```
root@Wohnzimmer:~# busybox --install opkg
--install: applet not found
```

It's Busybox system for that you need to download the packet manager archive against the target what they are using, for example: if it is ARM then compile using ARM toolchain in your host system then move the compiled binary to the target. After moving the compiled utility you can place the binary in `/sbin` dir of the `root fs`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experienece with this toolchain system I have no plan how to comlpile it, the Architechture seems to be MIPS. What do I have to do?

Comment: @Benjamin in that case you need to find the toolchain for MIPS in an internet and try to compile the source i.e, tar file need to untar and then compile it using the toolchain compiler that is how you can install the package. There is no straightforward way for you apart from this to install the package in busybox.

Comment: I have found this site: https://codescape.mips.com/components/toolchain/2018.09-02/downloads.html . Which toolkit do I have to use? Bare Metal or Linux?

Comment: you can type `uname -a`  in the busybox terminal it will show the Linux kernel version and in that case, use Linux toolchain. Before compiling and installing the source make sure the device has enough memory to add the compiled binary.

Comment: Ok, so it's the one for Linux, I have 33 MB Space on the Hue Bridge

Comment: So I have downloaded the toolkit and the source of opkg, but whatever I do I Always get an error: benni@Benni-PC:~/opkg-0.3.6/src$ ~/mips_compile/mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc --version
-bash: /home/benni/mips_compile/mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
benni@Benni-PC:~/opkg-0.3.6/src$ ~/mips_compile/mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc opkg.c
-bash: /home/benni/mips_compile/mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
benni@Benni-PC:~/opkg-0.3.6/src$